# IntelliSense in MATLAB Programming

Tags: intellisense

Does Matlab support **IntelliSense** feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliSense is Microsoft's name for auto-complete. Matlab has auto-complete. It doesn't have IntelliSense.

Comment: saying that matlab has auto complete is an overstatement. It is very VERY limited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, it's more of an auto-complete feature, check the following links,

[link1](http://www.techsource.com.sg/enews/01_09/emailer/talking.asp) , [link2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25217-intelligent-code-completion-for-matlab)